# How to do simple async calls in Python?

Tags: python, asynchronous

I have an async function call in python that looks like this:

```
response = client.invoke(
    FunctionName='CreateCatSpot',
    Payload="Meow"
)
```

I will be doing this call repeatedly and once it returns each time I want to do something with the response variable that the async function returns too. This seems like a very very simple example of async programming but I can't for the life of me figure out a simple way to do this in python. How do i do it?

Comment: you'll have to define an async method that does the iteration, register it with an event loop, and then start the event loop. Unless your program has something to do while waiting for response, though, why make it asynchronous?

Comment: @ToreEschliman I am actually stress testing my backend on AWS and invoking the AWS functions via boto in Python. I figure it's more like real world testing to test my back end asynchronously.

Comment: whatever io library `client.invoke` uses should provide an event loop that you can use. you're in python 3, right?

Comment: @ToreEschliman nope - Python 2.7.10 - does that make it harder?

Comment: depends on what you mean by harder. the quickest way to point b would probably be to use [gevent](http://www.gevent.org/), since it requires the least code re-writing to get there. but you should check with your cloud provider to see if they have suggestions about stress testing tools, rather than rolling your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import threading

def foo(client, function_name, payload):
    response = client.invoke(FunctioName=function_name, Payload=payload)
    # do something with the response

client = SomeClient()
values = [{"FunctionName": "...", "Payload": "..."}, {"FunctioName": "...", "Payload": "..."}, ...]
threads = [threading.Thread(target=foo, args=(client, v["FunctionName"], v["Payload"])) for v in values]
for t in threads:
    t.start()    # this will run foo() asynchronously
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using threads to run things in the background, rather than a true async message loop, look at the concurrent.futures module. It's standard in Python3 but a backport for Python 2 is available.

You can submit calls to an executor that runs them in the background. Either process the results yourself later, or bind a result callback to it that handles it for you once the call completes. Some example code:

```
import concurrent.futures as futures
import time

def handle_result(future):
    print("Result:", future.result())


def slow_function(argument):
    time.sleep(2)
    return argument


with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    async1 = executor.submit(slow_function, 1)
    async1.add_done_callback(handle_result)
    async2 = executor.submit(slow_function, 2)
    async2.add_done_callback(handle_result)
    async3 = executor.submit(slow_function, 3)
    async3.add_done_callback(handle_result)

    time.sleep(3)
```